# Getting error "expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token {" when trying to compile

Tags: c++

I get the following error when trying to compile my program:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token  {

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

{

vector<int> prime;


bool is_prime(int n)
{
for (int p = 0; p<prime.size(); ++p)
    if (n%prime[p]==0) return false;    // no remainder: prime[p] divided
return true;    // no smaller prime could divide
}
int main()

{

do
 {
prime.push_back(2); // consider the smallest prime

for (int i = 3; i<=100; ++i)    // test all integers [3:100]
    if (is_prime(i)) prime.push_back(i);    // add new prime to vector

cout << "Primes: ";
for (int p = 0; p<prime.size(); ++p)
    cout << prime[p] << '\n';

  }


}
```

Comment: What is that `{` after `using namespace std;` supposed to do?

Comment: And your `do` has no matching `while()` at the end of loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<int> prime;

bool is_prime(int n)
{
for (int p = 0; p<prime.size(); ++p)
   if (n%prime[p]==0) return false;    // no remainder: prime[p] divided
return true;    // no smaller prime could divide
}
int main()

{


prime.push_back(2); // consider the smallest prime

for (int i = 3; i<=100; ++i)    // test all integers [3:100]
if (is_prime(i)) prime.push_back(i);    // add new prime to vector

cout << "Primes: ";
for (int p = 0; p<prime.size(); ++p)
cout << prime[p] << '\n';

}
```

This is error-free version of code.

You don't need " do { " in main function as all lines in main are to be executed when program runs! Do while loop is used for looping . Read more about it here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop , but when the lines need to be executed without checking for any conditions ( like in this case) you don't need do while loop.

Also there is no need of " { " after using namespace std;

As commented by someone, I also strongly suggest you to read a book to clear these fundamentals!